# How to statistically detect a treshold effect over a dependent variable measured repeated times on the same population

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, maximum-entropy

I want to identify the level of a predictive variable X (with Gaussian distribution) able to induce a reduction in a variable y (with Poisson distribution), that has been measured over the same population, several times per day and across several days.

Here is a dataframe I am using to think about it, I have been unable to grasp a sound strategy for analysis. One worrying issue that seems to appear is that  the combination of these two variables leads to a scatter that might be confounded with a threshold imposed by x on y.

Would anybody have a suggestion to detect such a threshold reliably, should it exist?

```r
     hour=rep(1:24,30)
     DOY=rep(1:30, each=24)
     x=rnorm(length(hour), mean=15, sd=3)
     y=rpois(length(hour), lambda=10)
     df=data.frame(y, x, hour, DOY)
     plot(y ~ x)
```

Comment: I would suggest a model such as: `glmer(y ~ x + (1 | DOY), family = "poisson", data = df)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert, Do you think that would find the threshold? or simply tell me whether or not there is a significant change in Y due to X? I expect having daily series of Y in which some should be impacted by X and some should not.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a model such as:

```
glmer(y ~ x + (1 | DOY), family = "poisson")
```

Following comments on the question:

> Do you think that would find the threshold?

When you say "find the threshold", all you can do is to fit  a model which estimates this threshold (effect size). Once fitted you can assess the output as to whether the effect size is meaningful.

> or simply tell me whether or not there is a significant change in Y due to X?

It will estimate the effect size. Then you can assess this as to whether it is meaningful or not. Since you mention "significant", if you compute a p-value this will tell you the probability of observing this effect size, or indeed a larger one, if in fact the effect size was zero.

If you want to be able to detect a particular effect size, at a given level of statistical significance, then you should do a power calculation which will inform you of the sample size you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: Although  thankful for such useful food for thought, I do not feeel this question is answered yet. I was hoping there should be a way to identify a value in X that creates a significant decrease in Y, maybe i should separate X in categories and make a multiple comparison?